# How to call super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) with super() a specific instance

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Given this setup:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def bar(self):
        return Bar(self.arg1, self.arg2)


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().__init__(arg1, arg2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo(1, 2)
    print(foo.bar().arg1)
    print(foo.bar().arg2)
```

with `Bar` being a subclass of `Foo` is there a way to make `Bar` in `bar()` method in `Foo` recognize arg1 and arg2 of its superclass without passing them as parameters and without getting `arg1` and `arg2` out of `__init__()`?

Comment: Instantiating ``Bar(self.arg1, self.arg2)`` in a ``Foo`` method is completely unrelated to ``Bar`` being a subclass of ``Foo``. In general, there is no guarantee that subclasses take the same parameters during instantiation. Are your classes always "simple", in that all parameters become attributes? Are there any private attributes that should not be copied but re-initialised? Are attributes primitives (e.g. integers) or  compound objects (e.g. lists)? Note that ``Bar.__init__`` is superfluous.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The question isn't about making every instance of `Bar` have the same attributes as every instance of `Foo`, it's about getting the `Bar` instance inside of the `Foo`'s `bar` method to have the same attributes.

Comment: @NemanjaMirić I don't see how that relates to any of my requests for clarification.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yep, sorry. I misread a part of your comment.

Answer (score -1):

## Explanation

In order for `Bar` in `Foo`'s `bar` method to recognize the `arg1` and `arg2` methods of it's parent class without passing them as arguments, you can copy `Foo` object's attributes to `Bar` object's attributes.

This could either be done manually or automatically, though the automation comes with a cost of having to import the built-in module `inspect`.

## Solution

The way you could do this manually, is by just setting the attributes of the `Bar`'s object to be equal to `Foo` object's attributes. Since the `Bar` class inherits from the `Foo` class, you'll also need to override the `__init__` method inside of `Bar`:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def bar(self):
        temp_bar = Bar()
        temp_bar.arg1 = self.arg1
        temp_bar.arg2 = self.arg2
        return bar


class Bar(Foo):
    # Overrides the __init__ method
    def __init__():
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo(1, 2)
    print(foo.bar().arg1)
    print(foo.bar().arg2)
```

The second, automatic, way would be to copy the `Foo` object's custom-created attributes to `Bar` object's attributes. The `inspect` built-in module is needed here in order to get the attributes of the `Foo` object, while we can just update the `__dict__` attribute of the `Bar`'s object to copy the attributes:

```py
import inspect

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def bar(self):
        temp_bar = Bar()
        # Creates a dummy object
        dummy = dir(type('Dummy', (object,), {}))

        # Iterates through all Foo object's attributes
        for item in inspect.getmembers(self):
            # Since the dummy object only has built-in attributes,
            # only custom-created ones will be used (in this case arg1 and arg2)
            if item[0] not in dummy:
                # Copies each attribute to temp_bar
                setattr(temp_bar, *item)

        return temp_bar


class Bar(Foo):
    # Overrides the __init__ method
    def __init__(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo(1, 2)
    print(foo.bar().arg1)
    print(foo.bar().arg2)
```